# How to register new mimetypes not available in xfce4-mime-settings so that they are recognized with xdg-open under XFCE4?

Tags: xfce, chrome, mime-types, xdg-open

I am trying to register new mimetypes under XFCE4. In particular, I would like to register the protocol `zoommtg` so I can launch Zoom meetings from links in the webbrowser Chrome. Chrome will launch `xdg-open` here, which in turn launches `exo-open`. `exo-open` seems to ignore mimetype registrations of the type

```
xdg-mime default ZoomLauncher.desktop x-scheme-handler/zoommtg
```

Also manually adding

```
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/zoommtg=ZoomLauncher.desktop
```

to either `$HOME/.config/mimeapps.list` or `$HOME/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` does not lead to `xdg-open` via `exo-open` recognizing the `zoommtg` protocol.

How can new mimetypes be registered under XFCE4?

Notes:

`xfce4-mime-settings` does not offer the option to add new mimetypes.

The Chrome browser does not offer the option anymore (tested here: `Google Chrome V. 86`) to manually define commands to handle protocol types (`chrome://settings/handlers` only offers the option to allow websites to handle protocols (e.g. mailto: to a site with webmail)).

Comment: After you modify `mimeapps.list`, run `sudo update-desktop-database`.

Comment: sudo update-desktop-database does not seem to fix the issue in the case of XFCE4. xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/zoommtg does show the zoom launcher desktop file name (i.e. all should have been properly registered), but when running xdg-open on a zoom meeting link, I still get the error message: "The specified location is not supported."
This same procedure (xdg-mime default...) did not lead to any issues when tested under e.g. the Mate window manager instead of XFCE4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is almost indicated in the question: hinder `xdg-open` from choosing `exo-open`. A brute-force approach is to copy `/usr/bin/xdg-open` to `/usr/local/bin` (`/usr/local/bin` is earlier in `PATH` unless `PATH` has been modified) and to patch it to use `open_generic` instead of `exo_open` (unlike the `XFCE4`-specific `exo-open`, `open_generic` does honor `xdg` mime types)

```
--- /usr/bin/xdg-open   2020-03-31 03:20:01.000000000 +0200
+++ /usr/local/bin/xdg-open 2020-07-18 10:12:20.133132390 +0200
@@ -691,15 +691,11 @@
 
 open_xfce()
 {
-    if exo-open --help 2>/dev/null 1>&2; then
-        exo-open "$1"
-    elif gio help open 2>/dev/null 1>&2; then
-        gio open "$1"
-    elif gvfs-open --help 2>/dev/null 1>&2; then
-        gvfs-open "$1"
-    else
+    #if gvfs-open --help 2>/dev/null 1>&2; then
+    #    gvfs-open "$1"
+    #else
         open_generic "$1"
-    fi
+    #fi
 
     if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
         exit_success
```

Comment: This patch solution works. xdg-open now opens zoom meeting URLs.